# How to send the same email to all registered emails in SQLite DB - Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-studio

Upon the click of a "submit" button, I would like to send an email to all registered users that are stored in a SQLite database. Truthfully, I don't even know where to start. My thoughts are to access the email address from the database and store them in a list or array, but I'm not sure how I would then get that into the format needed to send the email (example: abc@gmail.com; xyz@yahoo.com). I'm familiar with clickListeners and don't need help setting that up, only figuring out how to access the email addresses stored in the database.

Below is the function within my DatabaseHelper class which I call in another class to insert users into the database.

```
    fun insertEmail(email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, company: String): Long {
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email)
        put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, firstName)
        put(COLUMN_LASTNAME, lastName)
        put(COLUMN_COMPANY, company)
    }
    val db = writableDatabase
    return db.insert(EMAIL_TABLE, null, values)
```

Below is simplified code I'm using to send the email.

```
        val recipients = arrayListOf<String>("abc@something.net", "xyz@something.net")
        val subject = "Test"
        val message = "Test"

        val mIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

        mIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
        mIntent.type = "text/plain"
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(recipients))
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Send Email"))
        } catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Function below to get emails from database.

```
    fun getEmails() {
    val db = readableDatabase
    val select = "$COLUMN_EMAIL"
    val cursor = db.query(EMAIL_TABLE, null, select, null, null, null, null)
    val emails = arrayListOf<String>()
    with(cursor) {
        while(moveToNext()) {
            val email = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("email"))
            emails.add(email)
        }
    }
    cursor.close()

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code to send one mail to two or three users.

Comment: Getting email addresses from a database has nothing to do with sending mails. You should only ask help for one problem to begin with.

Comment: I've added simplified code that I'm using to send the emails to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: You are only sending to one recipient. Please start with a list of recipients as it will pretty sure be a list you get from the database query.

Comment: This is the question I'm asking. How do I send an email to a list or recipients?

Comment: One does not send emails to a list. What are you talking about?

Comment: You have a list of recipients we assume. Then you use all recipients from the list in `arrayOf(recipient)`. Please adapt your code to do so. Start with a list of three recipients.

Comment: Dude why are you being so condescending? You said "please start with a list of recipients..." I'm asking how do I get the list of recipients. What I think you're trying to say, in a terrible way, is that I need to get the list of email addresses from the database and then place that list in the arrayOf() argument.

Comment: `I'm asking how do I get the list of recipients.` And i said: forget that database for a moment. Make an ArrayList and add three addresses to it. Then use that list for arrayOf(). Show your code.

Comment: I've edited the code above to show an arraylist, but I must have done something wrong. When I go to send the email, the "to" field is blank. It's not showing the emails in the arraylist.

Comment: "figuring out how to access the email addresses stored in the database" -- since you appear to be using old-school `SQLiteOpenHelper`, call `rawQuery()` on your  `SQLiteDatabase` with a suitable SQL query to return the desired email addresses. You will get a `Cursor` back, and you would iterate over that `Cursor` to get all the addresses.

Comment: "When I go to send the email, the "to" field is blank. It's not showing the emails in the arraylist" -- since `ACTION_SEND` is not designed to use `data`,  your `mailto:` is going to confuse some mail apps. If you want to use `mailto:`, then use `ACTION_SENDTO`, and set up the `mailto:` `Uri` the same way that you would on the Web, with your list of recipients, subject, and body. You would then eliminate the extras. Or, remove `mIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")` and stick with `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to implement these tomorrow. In the meantime, could you elaborate on "old-school" SQLiteOpenHelper? This is how I learned to use sqlite - is there an updated way to use it?

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe referring to [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), a newer way to interact with your local db without handling raw sql

Comment: In addition to Room, there is SQLDelight and other wrappers around low-level SQLite access.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I got the email to work when I create an arrayOf strings but I now am not sure how to get the emails out of the database and store them in an arrayOf strings. I created a function in my databaseHelper class, and am trying to call it and store it in val in another class but I get an error for type mismatch. See function in original post.